# Identical code works differently when running from aws lambda and from aws lambda but wrapped in a container image, but why?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've been tasked with configuring a Lambda function which is triggered automatically when a file is uploaded to a certain bucket in S3 and sends an email which describes each new file uploaded to the bucket, also the function is wrapped in a container image.

For testing purposes, I've configured two (duplicated) Lambda functions that does the same thing, each one of them watches a different bucket and one of them is wrapped in container image and other is not.. just a regular function.

This is the code of the function:
https://github.com/geek-kb/aws-s3-lambda/blob/main/app.py

When the function is running without being wrapped in a container image, it works like a charm, when it runs from the container image, it sends 3 emails per uploaded file.

Any idea why it could happen? It is the exact same code.

Edit (adding logs):
So I've just uploaded to the bucket two files (devops.png and mono_micro.png), this is how it looks in CloudWatch:
[image]

And this is the log itself:

```
2021-06-21T12:05:33.302+03:00   START RequestId: 2086551c-a555-4b95-9c1f-1f7dec6cd77b Version: $LATEST

2021-06-21T12:05:34.147+03:00   file_name: cicd.png, file_type: image/png, url: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/itai-test-bucket/cicd.png

2021-06-21T12:05:34.650+03:00   Email sent! Message ID:

2021-06-21T12:05:34.650+03:00   0102017a2dd160fa-d510446e-1f57-444b-b884-ea82c82e5b05-000000

2021-06-21T12:05:34.715+03:00   file_name: devops.png, file_type: image/png, url: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/itai-test-bucket/devops.png

2021-06-21T12:05:35.107+03:00   Email sent! Message ID:

2021-06-21T12:05:35.107+03:00   0102017a2dd16313-2db2f5f5-cbc7-4e71-be48-2cc7e2b35047-000000

2021-06-21T12:05:35.195+03:00   file_name: mono_micro.jpeg, file_type: image/jpeg, url: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/itai-test-bucket/mono_micro.jpeg

2021-06-21T12:05:35.589+03:00   Email sent! Message ID:

2021-06-21T12:05:35.589+03:00   0102017a2dd164ca-d988c32c-10c2-4757-9e32-aab33bca90a3-000000

2021-06-21T12:05:35.594+03:00   END RequestId: 2086551c-a555-4b95-9c1f-1f7dec6cd77b

2021-06-21T12:05:35.594+03:00   REPORT RequestId: 2086551c-a555-4b95-9c1f-1f7dec6cd77b Duration: 2291.52 ms Billed Duration: 3792 ms Memor
```

So there are two problems with that:

1. First of all, the fact that two events are created and for each event an email is sent for each file.
2. An email is sent also for the file that is already in the bucket (cicd.png).

Comment: I have 0 knowledge of AWS lambdas. But since you mentioned containers, it might be due to multiple replicas running on the containerized version.

Comment: Can you provide the logs? It seems like you are printing the event...